# DynamoDB how to query by one public latest item by each user?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

Here's my DynamoDB data structure.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------
id  |  author  |  status  |  content  |  createdAt
---------------------------------------------------------------------
id1 |  user1   |  PRIVATE |   pcon    |  2019-09-09T17:54:09.843Z
id1 |  user1   |  PUBLIC  |   hello   |  2019-09-08T17:54:09.843Z
id2 |  user2   |  PUBLIC  |   world   |  2019-09-07T17:54:09.843Z
id1 |  user1   |  PUBLIC  |   hello1  |  2019-09-07T17:54:09.843Z
---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

How to query one latest `PUBLIC` content from each user with DynamoDB?

expected query result:

```
items[
    {
        id: id1,
        author: user1,
        status: PUBLIC,
        content: hello,
        createdAt: 2019-09-08T17:54:09.843Z
    },
        {
        id: id2,
        author: user2,
        status: PUBLIC,
        content: world,
        createdAt: 2019-09-07T17:54:09.843Z
    },
]
```

I was able to get all `PUBLIC` items with the below code but can't find way to get one latest items from them.(Amplify custom resolver mapping template)

```
{
  "version": "2017-02-28",
  "operation": "Query",
  "query": {
    "expression": "#privacy = :privacy",
    "expressionNames": {
        "#privacy": "privacy"
    },
    "expressionValues": {
        ":privacy": {
            "S": "PUBLIC"
        }
    }
  },
  "scanIndexForward": #if( $context.args.sortDirection == "ASC" ) true #else false #end,
  "limit": $limit,
  "nextToken": #if( $context.args.nextToken ) "$context.args.nextToken" #else null #end,
  "index": "privacy"
}
```

Comment: questions: how many users are you planning to have in the table (order of magnitude, no need for an exact number)? how many items in total are you planning to have (again, order of magnitude)? when you "query one latest PUBLIC content from each user"  do you need it for all users or just for a selected subset? do you need just the first N entries? if so, what's N? is this a one-off query or is it going to run repeatedly? at what frequency? is it ok in your application if the result from this query are slightly outdated? (let's say a few seconds? a few minutes? a few hours?)

Comment: sorry for all these questions but there is a huge solution space and this questions help zero-in on the right solution

Comment: Currently have 6,540 users from probably over 20k PUBLIC content. I definitely want this to be flexible to accommodate for users and data.

Comment: This will be queried when users get to the PUBLIC content page with Load more button to show older content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to introduce a second table and a GSI (Global secondary index) on it with the following structure:

- `userId` <-- table's partition key
- `category` <-- GSI's partition key
- `createdAt` <-- GSI's sort key
- `id`

The `userId` attribute is a value that uniquely identify a user (IIUC it could actually be the `author` field from the table described in your post)

The `category` attribute may initially seem a bit weird: it contains one of several hard-coded value. At the moment I can only think about one such value: `"public_content_page"`. Still, even if no new category will come up in the future this attribute is needed as the partition key of the GSI (so we cannot avoid it).

The `createdAt`, `id` attributes are identical to the ones in the table described in your post.

To get the items in the order that you want you need to query the GSI as follows:

```
{ 
  "TableName": <your_table_name>,
  "IndexName": <your_GSI_name>
  "KeyConditionExpression": "category = :v1",
  "ExpressionAttributeValues": {":v1": {"S": "public_content_page"}}
   "ScanIndexForward": false,
}
```

Because the primary key of the table is `userId` this table will hold just a single item per user.

Because all items in that table have the same `category` value and the GSI's partition key is `category` attribute, then querying the GSI is querying the entire set of item in that table.

Because the `createdAt` attribute is the GSI's sort key the results returned by this query will be sorted chronologically.

Of course, you need to populate this table. Basically, each time you `put()`/`update()`/`delete()` an item from the first table (the one described in your post) you'll need to do an `update()` in the second table (the one introduced in my answer). In that update, you'll need to use a `ConditionExpression` to make sure you overwrite an item only if the new `createdAt` value is greater than the `createdAt` value at the item.

You need to keep in mind that there is a slight chance that the `update()` of the second table will not get executed (because your process will terminate after updating the first table and just before updating the second one). You can either do an scheduled scan which rebuilds the second table from the first at some periodic schedule, or you can [triggers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.Lambda.html)).

### Additional thoughts

ths GSI presented here just holds the `id` of an item from the first table. Thus, in order to get the actual item's content you'll need to take the query's result and do multiple `get()`s on the first table using the `id` values returned by the query. You can use [BatchGetItem](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_BatchGetItem.html) to do several `get()` operations in one request. Alternatively, you can use a different structure of the second table: instead of holding the `id` of an item from the first table, it will hold the `content` value. This will free you from the additional `get()`s. On the other hand, it will make financial costs higher (the second table will now store more data) and it will make updates to the second table more frequent (because the `content` field is likely to be a field which is edited often, and each such edit will end up with an update to the second table).

Finally, you instead of doing an `update()` on the second table (which also entail  lambda triggers/periodic scans) you can use `TransactWriteItems` to updates both tables in a single transaction. You will still need to use a condition on the `createdAt` attribute, though.